# Delphi Records getting Access violation ... of address

Tags: memory, freepascal, pascalscript

I'm new to Delphi/Pascal syntax (although this might actually be FreePascal or PascalScript). I'm using it in a macro software to interact with the macro software's APIs. I'm trying to contact the macro software owners to let me know exactly what the scripting engine uses.

Anyways, I'm running into issues using Records with memory access and for the life of me can't figure it out. With the code I posted below, the exact error I'm getting is:

```
Module: "", Line: 53, Message: Access violation at address 02BC88A8. Read of address 00280060
```

Line 53 is: `bars[Length(bars) - 1].Y := foos[i].B;`

```
uses SysUtils;

type
  TFoo = record
    A: cardinal;
    B: int64;
    C: string;
  end;
  TBar = record
    X: cardinal;
    Y: int64;
    Z: string;
  end;
```

```
var
  foos: array of TFoo;
  bars: array of TBar;
  i: Integer;
  counter: Integer;
```

I abstracted out some example which seems to give me same error to my actual code. I can't post the actual code because it would be meaningless and won't run outside the macro software api and the software I'm trying to control -- both require licenses.

I'm trying to create `bars` which are a subset of `foos` with some transformations applied (including identity).

If it's useful to know: My actual script reads from a file into "foos" where each record corresponds to a line in a file, and each element corresponds to a comma delimited field. I basically created a barebones CSV parser. This CSV acts as my initial script configuration. I then have to iterate through the configuration and check state of the app for which I'm writing macros. If certain conditions are met, I want to copy the values of my configuration from foo into bar, but some transformations need to be applied based on the state of the application I want to control. Then, "bars" is ultimately used to generate the macro commands which get run against the app.

The actual app gets errors like this, and doesn't consistently fail in same place when looping through foos:

```
Module: "Main", Line: 119, Message: Access violation at address 02BC88A8. Read of address 00320044
```

and that line of code is the same form as in my example code here:

```
FinalConfig[Length(FinalConfig) - 1].Qty    := InitialConfig[i].Qty;
```

This example program doesn't consistently fail, so I wrapped it in a loop. However, in the macro app I'm using, the script seems to fail more consistently when I use the loop (on counter = 1, lol).

I do not know what I'm missing, please help.

```
begin
  counter:= 0;
  while (true) do
  begin
    counter:= counter + 1;
    print(counter);
    SetLength(foos, 3);
    with foos[0] do
      begin
        A := 1;
        B := 2;
        C := 'three';
      end;
    with foos[1] do
      begin
        A := 4;
        B := 5;
        C := 'six';
      end;
    with foos[2] do
      begin
        A := 7;
        B := 8;
        C := 'nine';
      end;

    for i:= 0 to Length(foos) - 1 do
    begin
      if foos[i].B > 3 then
      begin
        SetLength(bars, Length(bars) + 1);
        bars[Length(bars) - 1].X := foos[i].A;
        bars[Length(bars) - 1].Y := foos[i].B;
        bars[Length(bars) - 1].Z := foos[i].C;
      end;
    end;

    for i:= 0 to Length(bars) - 1 do
    begin
      print(Format('X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %s', [bars[i].X, bars[i].Y, bars[i].Z]));
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Expected output:

```
X: 4, Y: 5, Z: six
X: 7, Y: 8, Z: nine
```

Comment: Other programs that happen to use pascalscript are not Delphi. Delphi is a specific commercial product. You've also not identified the product you're using or provided a [mre] that demonstrates the issue; the code you've posted references `foos` with an index, while you've not provided any information about where `foos` comes from or how it is populated.

Comment: Tried this in Delphi 10, Seattle. Had to change `print` into `writeln`, but apart from that no errors. It did give the expected output.

Comment: Same as @GolezTrol here. Your problem, whatever it is, is not in the code you provided. Please also, whenever you get an error message, show it verbatim, and all of it.

Comment: @KenWhite Perhaps it's PascalScript. I do not know. How could I find this out? I didn't reveal the product I'm using because it's an obscure homebrew engine for automating tasks in a game.

Comment: I don't know if it's the specific PascalScript or anothe Pascal-based scripting language. I do know for a fact that it isn't Delphi, because Delphi code is compiled and linked into an executable before it can be run, and you're not doing so, so the Delphi tag doesn't apply here. There's no such thing as a *limited version of Delphi* which can be used inside third-party software.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for the feedback. I'm trying to get in contact with the macro software's owners to see what scripting engine they're using exactly. I have a hint it might be FreePascal but not sure yet. Either way, perhaps my edits have enough detail now to start getting help and feedback on my issue?

Comment: I no longer get the bug if switch to using a `packed record` and set my string-type parameter to a ShortString e.g. `string[29]` However, the error seemed to always be on my int64 fields.